# Add to Qt project contents of directory as OS X bundle resource

Tags: macos, qt, .app, macdeployqt

I want to add to Qt project a contents of directory which contains: a bash script and a few java files inside other various sub-directories. I tried INCLUDEPATH and it didn't work.

I don't want the directory in the build directory, I want it inside the .app file (OS X bundle) so when I use `macdeployqt` they are all packed inside a `.dmg` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files from this directory you have to add this way:

```
APP_JAVA_FILES.files = <this directry>/Class1.java \
                       <this directry>/Class2.java
APP_JAVA_FILES.path = Contents/Resources

APP_JAVA_FILES2.files = <this directory>/sub-dir/Class3.java \
                       <this directory>/sub-dir/Class4.java
APP_JAVA_FILES2.path = Contents/Resources/sub-dir

APP_BASH_FILES = <this directory>/script.sh
APP_BASH_FILES.path = Contents/Resources

QMAKE_BUNDLE_DATA += APP_JAVA_FILES APP_JAVA_FILES2 APP_BASH_FILES
```

[Here is a documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#qmake-bundle-data) about this.